# How to get TOP 1 result from a LINQ left join without APPLY

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have a master table and I intend to use a left join with LINQ.

Unfortunately the left join multiplies the result (*I need only a top 1 result from that*).

Here comes the problem: **my query should have SQL 8 conformance**.

So when I use the following query:

```
var query = from user in context.User                       
            join group in context.Groups on user.ID equals group.GroupID into groupJoin
            from subGroup in groupJoin.Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
              Name = user.Name,
              GroupName = subGroup!=null ? subGroup.Name : null
            };
```

I get this exception:

> The execution of this query requires the APPLY operator, which is not
>   supported in versions of SQL Server earlier than SQL Server 2005.

How could I replace my query to have SQL8 conformance?

Comment: LINQ is too broad. Please provide the appropriate tags and info - e.g. entity framework, version etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have no EF4 to test (it does the trick in the latest EF6), but you can try to force usage of a SQL subquery expression(s) like this:

```
var query = from user in context.User
            select new
            {
                Name = user.Name,
                GroupName = (from g in context.Groups where g.GroupId == user.Id select g.Name).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

Used your linq-query without take(1) and after that use next code:

```
query = query.Take(1);
```

Comment: I guess it would limit the final query and would take only 1 User..but I need to limit the joined table.